# Javascript can't get an input element inside of a gridview

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I an asp.net page that lets a site administrator select a user to be a 'systems chair'.  To do this, I list the users in a gridview, and have a column of radio buttons to show who the current chair is, or to change the assigned chair.  I'm using an html input (type=radio) for the buttons.  When the page loads, if the 'system' has a 'chair' assigned to it, I need to check the related radiobutton.  I'm trying to do this with javascript or jquery.  The scripts I've tried are:

jquery try 1:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function initRadioButtons() {
      $("#user268").attr('checked', 'checked');
   }
</script>
```

jQuery try 2:
     
          function initRadioButtons() {
             $("#user268").prop('checked', true);
       }

javascript (rb is set to null):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      function initRadioButtons() {
         var rb = document.getElementById(user268");
      }
</script>
```

Here is the gridview from my .aspx file:

```
<Custom:GridView ID="gvUsers" DataSourceID="dsUsers" CellPadding="3" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
     ArrowUpImageUrl="~/images/SortUpArrow.jpg" ArrowDownImageUrl="~/images/SortDownArrow.jpg"
     Width="100%" ShowWhenEmpty="true" EmptyDataText="No Users Returned" DataKeyNames="userID"
    AllowSorting="true" runat="server">
       <Columns>
          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="AST Chair" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle"
           SortExpression="IsChair">
             <ItemTemplate>
                <input type="radio" id='user<%# Eval("userID") %>' name="isChair" value='<%# Eval("userID") %>' onclick="radioButtonClicked(this);" />
                </ItemTemplate>
          </asp:TemplateField>
          <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Username" DataField="userName" sortExpression="userName" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" />
          <asp:BoundField HeaderText="First Name" DataField="FirstName" SortExpression="FirstName" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" />
          <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Last Name" DataField="LastName" SortExpression="LastName" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" />
    </Columns>
</Custom:GridView>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Run the application and then inspect the element.  Is the Id of the element what you expected it to be?  Asp.Net web forms will automatically add the Id's of the parent containers to it.  Your second snippet should have a quite in front of `user268` also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest two things. First the JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
       initRadioButtons();
   });

   function initRadioButtons() {
      $(".user268").attr('checked', 'checked'); // notice i changed to class for next one
   }
</script>
```

Then I would check the view source of the running page, is it showing this in the ID field?

```
id='user<%# Eval("userID") %>'
```

I think you have to do that line differently. It has to be `runat="server"` for data binding to work. Because you have `runat="server"` then you actually have to use a class because webforms will auto assign an ID. It also has to be the full attribute value contained in the `<%# %>`. So my guess is this line should be more like:

```
<input runat="server" type="radio" class='<%# string.Format("user{0}", Eval("userID")) %>' name="isChair" value='<%# Eval("userID") %>' onclick="radioButtonClicked(this);" />
```

Now we have got this far I think the next problem you will have is that you are using an `<input>` tag in a GridView so it wont be posted back as part of the binding. Normally you would use `<asp:RadioButton>` to do this.

Comment: Your first suggestion gets the win.  I was calling the initRadioButtons() function from the Page_Load() function in the code behind - so the javascript was running before the page was fully populated.  Moving the call to the $(document).ready(function()) made all the difference.  However, it is allowing me to use the databind on the html <input> element, in the gridview - go figure.

Comment: ah OK glad it worked, it was just a guess about the `input` tag, and I realised after I clicked post you are only `eval()` so it wouldn't need to post the value back anyway.